# Greek letter in math mode appears lower than the rest of the statement

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

This is my first time using the math mode. My problem is visible in the following screen capture. I find that the lower-case *chi* letter is rendered lower than the latin characters. Is that normal?

[image]

A test text and my relevant packages are below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}
\usepackage[final,babel]{microtype}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua:  $\chi^{2} = 123.4567$ Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. That's the way the letter is meant to be. Same thing for `\gamma`, `\eta`, and `\mu`. `\phi\psi\zeta\xi` also have descenders (not a complete list). Nothing to worry about.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The lowercase greek letter χ (chi) is set lower — not unlike a roman letter g or y.